# JPA one to one join on @Id column. Joined column not updated in reference table

Tags: postgresql, join, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables Car and Status.
The relationship is one to one Car has-a Status

```
 Car Table
 Id (PK)
 Name
 status_id(FK)

Status Table
Id(PK)
status_code
```

the relation is **car.status_id=status.id**

Entities

```
@Entity
class Car{
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Id
  Long id;
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "status_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable =  false, updatable = false)
  Status status
 
 @Column(name="status_id")
  Integer statusId
  ..
}

@Entity
class Status{
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private int status_code;

}
```

When I save a Car Object:

```
Car{ id=null, name="my car", status_id=null, status={id=null, status_code=123}}

repo.saveAndFlush(car)
```

The data that gets saved in the table is:

```
Car
|Id|name|status_id|
|1|mycar|null     | <------THIS NULL IS MY ISSUE
```

(this should be updated with id inserted in status table. how to achieve that ?

```
Status
|id|status_code|
|1 |123        |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to define the statusId field seperately.
Just remove the below lines and it will work as expected.

```
 @Column(name="status_id")
  Integer statusId
```

Comment: also had to remove insertable =  false, updatable = false. Worked, thanks !